# How to create a kafka message without producer?

Tags: go, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-go

I want to create a basic test case without bootstrapping producer, consumer and an instance of kafka for a test. I'm stuck with creating a basic message somehow and cannot find my error.
This is the struct definition from the [confluent-kafka-go](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/blob/1d5067b0f4f88f4167cb66a78ab4c4f3ec3b5786/kafka/message.go#L73) sdk:

```
// Message represents a Kafka message
type Message struct {
    TopicPartition TopicPartition
    Value          []byte
    Key            []byte
    Timestamp      time.Time
    TimestampType  TimestampType
    Opaque         interface{}
    Headers        []Header
}
```

My basic message creation looks like this.
I already verified that topicPartition struct and validImageUploadMessageAsBytes are valid objects.

```
kafkaMessage := kafka.Message{
        TopicPartition: topicPartition,
        Value:          validImageUploadMessageAsBytes,
        Key:            messageKey,
        Headers:        nil,
    }
```

I also tried the following approach to make sure it does not fail because of some data I provide into the message:

```
emptyMessage := new(kafka.Message)
    emptyMessage.TopicPartition = topicPartition
    emptyMessage.Value = []byte("")
    emptyMessage.Key = []byte("")
```

This example produces the same output as in the picture below

When debugging it the test with GoLand (2021.3.3) I am presented with this variable value

[image: Failed to compute node presentation]

Comment: You don't have a producer here, anyway, so what exactly is the question? Have you tried just printing the `kafkaMessage` instead of trying to use the debugger?

Comment: My question is how to create a message without using a producer. I want tu use the existing kafka.Message struct but am currently unable and can't find my error.

Comment: The process of creating a message is decoupled from the producer instance. As you can see, the Struct doesn't have a Producer instance. What "error" are you referring to? The `failed to compute` just means there is no string/debugging  representation that your IDE can compute, its not a runtime error of your code

Comment: You both were right - I let myself confuse by the message shown from the IDE that it failed to compute, whereas the actual struct was created and everything worked as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is working properly, it is just a display issue by the IDE GoLand (2021.3.3)